# Convert output of a query to JSON format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given the following:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b72da5e9263d55490fa0809c52577083

I need to have the `secondname` in the results too, and the output should be in JSON format.

parent -> children, then each child again its children, etc.

```
{ "Main Product" : 
    { "title" : "MP",
      "children" : 
      [ 
        { "Addon Product" : 
          { "title" : "AP",
            "children" : 
            [ 
              { "subAddon Product" : 
                { "title" : "SAP" } },

          ...
```

of course any better idea for output is welcome. SInce i see export is JSON is too difficult, perhaps export to a more easy format ie csv, xml, so that i could then generate the json.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=20b9fe29b8e0af9c7ec84f64873bcc1b

Comment: Your title used to refer to SQL Server 2012, which I have replaced with a tag. However, in your db<>fiddle you use the SQL Server 2016 database engine. Which version is the correct one?

Comment: 2012 is what i have unfortunately